# Grunt transforms relative paths to absolute

Tags: css, fonts, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

(I'm a Grunt newcomer, so bear with me)

I'm trying to use grunt with the sass version of font-awesome, but when the final stylesheet is generated, the paths for the font files are absolute, and similar to:

/users/my_user_name/git/project_name/.tmp/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/font-awesome.ttf

Instead of, as I would expect:

../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/font-awesome.ttf

If I look at the generated stylesheet in the .tmp directory, the paths here are relative, so I suspect it is one of the other components like usemin that is messing it up.

I've used yeoman to setup my project.

Any ideas what the problem is or someone who can provide an example of a working gruntfile with font-awesome?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `$fa-font-path` variable in `font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss`?

Comment: Yes, and the .css file generated in .tmp/styles/main.css does reflect the path as a relative path.

Comment: Could you add the part of your grunt file to the question?